# Homology of Grassmannians

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I am curious if anyone is aware of the limits (in terms of $n$ and $k$) of the known integral (co)homology of real Grassmannians. I have been mostly unsuccessful in finding literature on the topic, so any knowledge/references would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/1309.5520 Claims to do it

Answer (score 0):

E. Brown computest in
https://www-jstor-org.vu-nl.idm.oclc.org/stable/2044298?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents the integral cohomology of the infinite grassmannians.